# Convert March 2015 to 03/2015 and make into date

Tags: mysql, date

I have a column which holds values in the format 'June 2015', 'July 2015', 'March 2014', 'February 2016'.

I need to convert these into the format 06/2015, 07/2015, 03/2014, 02/2016.. but also make them a date so I can sort by this column.

I currently have the following select:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(quotation.quotation_exp_conversion_date, ' ', 1),3), '%b')), '/', SUBSTRING_INDEX(quotation.quotation_exp_conversion_date, ' ', -1)) AS exp_conversion_date
FROM quotation
WHERE quotation.quotation_status = 'LIVE'
ORDER BY exp_conversion_date ASC
```

There are 2 problems. This query converts the values into the format '6/2015', '7/2015', '3/2014', '2/2016' (without the leading 0 for single digit months), and does not order by correctly as the YEAR is not taken into account - so they are ordered:
'2/2016', '3/2014', '6/2015', '7/2015'

I tried wrapping it all in the `DATE()` function but that just returned `NULL` for all values.

Any ideas on how to achieve what I want?

Thanks

Comment: If you're converting it to a data type like `DATE`, it won't *have* a format - that's the point, it holds a date, not a *string* representation of a date. But if you're happy to stick with strings, why not convert to `YYYY-MM` format - a format where *alphabetical* sorting produces the desired sort order naturally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STR_TO_DATE works for me with a format of '%M %Y':

```
mysql> select str_to_date('July 2015', '%M %Y');
+-----------------------------------+
| str_to_date('July 2015', '%M %Y') |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2015-07-00                        |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)
```

Expand your question if there's some reason you can't do the same.

To turn that into a full query (which I obviously can't test without your tables, so *caveat lector*):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d, '%m/%Y')
FROM 
  (SELECT str_to_date(quotation_exp_conversion_date, '%M %Y') AS d FROM quotation)
ORDER BY d ASC;
```

Comment: Hmm, is "00" a valid day, though? ;-)

Comment: @Ja͢ck: I don't think it matters if you never use the day number.  It's sufficient for sorting and for formatting back to the original form.  I guess it's DATE's equivalent of NULL...

Comment: Thank you my friend. This is slightly more easy to ready than my query too ;)